# Trouble parsing XML response from curl_exec

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am submitting the contents of an HTML form to a 3rd-party service using cURL, and it shoots me back an XML response. But no matter what I'm doing I can't seem to parse that XML response to customize the display of the results.

Here is the code for processing the form (note a few ID numbers have been censored):

```
<?php
 $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'] ;
 $LastName = $_POST['LastName'] ;
 $Zip = $_POST['Zip'] ;
 $EmailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'] ;
 $PrimaryPhoneNumber = $_POST['PrimaryPhoneNumber'] ;
 $DateofBirth = $_POST['DateofBirth'] ;



$myvars = '&VID=' . '****' . '&LID=' . '****' . '&AID=' . '****' . '&FirstName=' . $FirstName . '&LastName=' . $LastName .
       '&EmailAddress=' . $EmailAddress . '&PrimaryPhoneNumber=' . $PrimaryPhoneNumber . '&Zip=' . $Zip . '&DateofBirth=' . $DateofBirth;


if ($FirstName!='' && $LastName!='' && $Zip!='' && $EmailAddress!='' && $PrimaryPhoneNumber!='' && $DateofBirth!='') {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://secure.leadexec.net/leadimport.asmx/LeadReceiver');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_exec ($c);
    curl_close ($c);

} else {
    echo '<p>Please make sure you have filled out the form completely</p>';
}
?>
```

This is the raw output of the response I get back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PostResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.leadproweb.com/">
  <isValidPost>false</isValidPost>
  <ResponseType>Duplicate_Lead</ResponseType>
  <ResponseDetails>Duplicate Lead, Last Received On: 9/27/2013 2:17:26 PM</ResponseDetails>
  <LeadIdentifier>20889333</LeadIdentifier>
  <VendorAccountAssigned>0</VendorAccountAssigned>
  <PendingQCReview>false</PendingQCReview>
  <Price>0</Price>
  <RedirectURL />
</PostResponse>
```

When I try using methods like **SimpleXmlElement** or **simplexml_load_string()** to parse the XML, they seem to be ignored and I can't get rid of the raw XML output unless I remove the **curl_exec($c)** line.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the output: `$response = curl_exec( $c );`? How were you planning to parse it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing exactly that, and then doing `print_r ($response);` but it gives me no result.

Comment: @Evster What's the result of `var_dump($response);`?

Comment: @Evster Take a look at the page's source code (right-click in your browser, choose "View source code")!

Comment: OK so `print_r ($response);` actually gives me a value of `1` when I view the source code. Calling `var_dump($response);` gives me `bool(true)` in the source code. But I should note that the source code is still spitting out all of the unwanted XML before displaying this data as noted in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

to get the value (string) of the response; otherwise, `curl_exec` just returns a boolean (success/failure). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Then you replace the line

```
curl_exec( $c );
```

with

```
$response = curl_exec( $c );
```

And finally you parse the response string with a parser of your choice.

Comment: Thanks this appears to be the solution I was looking for!

Comment: I should also note that I need to eliminate the direct call to `curl_exec( $c );` and instead assign it to a variable, otherwise I problems with duplicate results.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion Floris. You are correct. What I meant was that I needed to _replace_ the call to `curl_exec($c);` with `$response = curl_exec($c);`. If I left both calls in my code it wouldn't work.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make the point unambiguous. We can now delete these comments...